# Is it possible to force the disabling of access tokens in Azure AD B2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I want to disable the access token and have the user log in again when the network is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot revoke the access token.

You can [revoke the refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) so that when the access token expires the user will not be granted a new refresh token and will have to log in again.

Comment: If that's the case, is it impossible to log in again due to the network being cut off?

Comment: If you can't reach B2C, you can't log in.

Comment: But remember B2C has a lot of redundancy (multiple sites) so it depends where the network is down.

Comment: It was my fault.
Forces the user to log out when the network is disconnected. (revoke access toke & refresh token?).
Next, show the login page when the network is connected.
Can I disable the access token by disabling the refresh token right after I disconnect from the network?